# Bash script not working as expected. Wrong file listing behaviour

Tags: bash

I've been following this tutorial (the idea can also be found in other posts of SO)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

This is my test script:

```
function getAllTests {

   allfiles=$TEST_SCRIPTS/*

   # Getting all stests in the 
   if [[ $1 == "s" ]]; then
      for f in $allfiles 
      do
         echo $f
      done
   fi
}
```

The idea is to print all files (one per line) in the directory found in TEST_SCRIPTS.

Instead of that this is what I get as an output:

```
/path/to/dir/*
```

(The actual path obviously, but this is to convey the idea).

I have tried the followign experiment on bash. Doing this

```
a=(./*)
```

And this read me all files in the current directory into a as an array. However if anything other than ./ is used then it does not work.

How can I use this procedure with a directory other than ./?

Comment: what about using something like `find $TEST_SCRIPTS -type f`?

Comment: the above code will be inconsistent when you have a file named `bad*file` inside `$TEST_SCRIPTS`. using for loop to iterate through files is generally a bad idea. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are no matches, the wildcard is not expanded.

I speculate that `TESTSCRIPTS` contains a path which does not exist; but without access to your code, there is obviously no way to diagnose this properly.

Common solutions include `shopt -s nullglob` which causes the shell to replace the wildcard with nothing when there are no matches; and explicitly checking for the expanded value being equal to the wildcard (in theory, this could misfire if there is a single file named literally `*` so this is not completely bulletproof!)

By the by, the `allfiles` variable appears to be superfluous, and you should generally be much more meticulous about quoting.  See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) for details.

```
function getAllTests {
   local nullglob
   shopt -q nullglob || nullglob=reset
   shopt -s nullglob
   # Getting all stests in the         # fix sentence fragment?
   if [[ $1 == "s" ]]; then
      for f in "$TEST_SCRIPTS"/*; do   # notice quotes
         echo "$f"                     # ditto
      done
   fi
   # Unset if it wasn't set originally
   case $nullglob in 'reset') shopt -u nullglob;; esac
}
```

Setting and unsetting `nullglob` inside a single function is probably excessive; most commonly, you would set it once at the beginning of your script, and then write the script accordingly.

Comment: Effectively. I thought the path was ok, but It was wrong. Since the code work as is, when I fixed that. Should I delete this thread? What is the appropiate course?

Comment: Keeping the question is fine, although it should be flagged as a duplicate if we find an older question with substantially the same contents; it seems likely that this has been asked before, though I could not find an obvious duplicate by cursory searching.